# 100% Vertical layout with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a very simple layout using bootstrap 3 but it is resulting in a lot of trouble.

I'm trying to build something similar to this that of [Operator](https://operator.com/). It's a very simple landing page.

I'm just not getting the vertical alignment right using css and bootstrap. Should I be using JS for this? It seems so simple?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Paulie_D whilst you were providing irrelevant comments other members were providing answers. Thanks for the downvote :-)

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- You can see this blog may be its helpful to you
http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-forms.php

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes